# Add a Json object to JSON Array using scala play

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

This is my current json:

```
{"name":"James",
    "child": {"id":1234,"name":"Ruth",
        "grandchild":{"id":1111,"name":"Peter"}
    }
}
```

I want to make it like this:

```
{"name":"James",
    "child": [{"id":1234,"name":"Ruth",
        "grandChild":[{"id":1111,"name":"Peter"}]
     }]
}
```

Below is the code:

```
def getParentJSON = {
    Json.obj(
        "name"->"James",
        "child"->getChildJson
    )
}

def getChildJSON = {
    Json.obj(
        "id"->"1234",
        "name"->"Ruth",
        "grandChild"->getGrandChildJson
    )       
}

def getGrandChildJSON = {
    Json.obj(
        "id"->"1111",
        "name"->"Peter"
    )       
}
```

I tried to use JsArray.append(getParentJSON).
But it didn't worked.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Json.arr`:

```
def getParentJSON = {
  Json.obj(
    "name" -> "James",
    "child" -> Json.arr(getChildJSON)
  )
}

def getChildJSON = {
  Json.obj(
    "id" -> "1234",
    "name" -> "Ruth",
    "grandChild" -> Json.arr(getGrandChildJSON)
  )
}
```

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson#Using-class-construction